# Javabeans convention for one field for different types?

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, javabeans, setter

Can I have one `setSource()` setter with two versions for two different argument types, i.e. `setSource(InputStream)` and `setSource(TargetDataLine)`?

Internally I hold the value in `Object` field and dispatch processing based on RTTI, but I wonder if bean-realted libraries like Spring will accept such setters gracefully? I.e. will I able to put values of different types into one `source` bean field?

Comment: Did you try it out? What happened?

Comment: I don't tell you, oh the great brain :)

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't really seem right. What does `getSource()` return ? An `Object` ? If so, I'd suggest that your `setSource()` accepts an `Object`.

Obviously that seems too 'generic', and I wonder if this problem indicates that your modelling is incorrect, and that you need two specialised subclasses handling different source types.

Failing that, why not be explicit and have `setStreamSource()` / `setTargetDataLineSource()` with the correct types, and enforce the setting of one or the other, but not both (I still think the specialisation is the way to go, however).

Comment: Yes I think absolutely like you including problems and possible solutions. But the question is "what if". Will it work? P.S. Bad design is not mine but Sun/Oracle's since they did similar types unrelated.

Comment: What if ? I suspect (since Javabeans is a *convention*) that it would depend upon the implementation

Comment: Also this means that bean idea damages polymorphism :)

Comment: so the question is what if in the latest spring implementation?